Extract list of items of a dropdown menu using BeatifulSoup
I have been trying numerous ways but this website is proving very hard to scrape via bs4. Here's the URL: https://www.nseindia.com/option-chain
I am trying to extract the option value found in the snip below on one of the matches. The aim is to extract all "option" values from the dropdown menu into a list. here's the list I'm looking for:
['AARTIIND', 'ABB', 'ABBOTINDIA', 'ABCAPITAL',.....]
Snippet
I tried using bs4 and I was able to get the parent (that has the id="select_symbol") of the all "option" tags I'm looking for, but when digging into what I have fetched, the result I got was an empty list.
Here's the code that I have set up for this task:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/option-chain'
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

# Send a GET request to the URL

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

select_ = soup.find("select", {"id":"select_symbol"})

option_content = soup.find("select", {"id":"select_symbol"}).find_all("option")` 

At the end, this is what I get:
option_content = []


Please can you provide the code rather than using an image snippet?

If you look at the result of soup, you'll see that there is no option to select_symbol.
# Save soup to a text file 
with open(r'path/to/folder/result.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(soup.prettify()) # [...]<select aria-labelledby="selectSymbolLbl" id="select_symbol"> </select>[...]

This is because the data that you are looking for is loaded from another location. Maybe a Json file or an API call or whatever. 
If you check the network tab on your browser console when you go on the webpage, you'll see that a GET request for master-quote webpage is sent. The master-quote webpage contain API in his url.. That's an API call !
The Response of the request return a list :
[
"AARTIIND",
"ABB",
"ABBOTINDIA",
...]

That's the data you are looking for. Be sure to redo what i have done and understand this concept before copy/paste the script below who print the data you need :
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/master-quote'
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.text)

I hope it will help you for now and futur

Arthur. Were you obliged to put the word "stupidly" in your answer? Is that fair?

Sorry, I don’t want to offense anyone. I mean, don’t copy/paste without understand where was the mistake. I edited my answer

No worries. Understood. Thanks for your enlightenment regarding that list being obtained via an API.
